# Using IsBlank() & <> will cause my filter to raise this error "Error when trying to retrieve data from network:

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have this formula to filter SharePoint list:

```
ForAll(relatedNetworkIDsFortheCurrentBookingCalendar, 
   Collect(colDelegableresults, Filter(BookingCalendarNetwork, 
             ActiveStatus.Value = "Active"
             And 'Network ID' = ThisRecord.ID
             And (
                IsBlank(varBKID) Or 'Booking Calendar ID'<>varBKID
            )
        ))
);
```

But i am getting this runtime error on it :

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1699977981944.png]

any advice?

Comment: what's your status, did you apply the fix described in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-isblank-isempty#isblank) :

> To test specifically for a blank value use `if( Value = Blank(), ...`  instead of `IsBlank`. The `IsBlank` function considers empty tables as not blank, and `IsEmpty` should be used to test a table.

But, this is **not** the issue. As `BookingCalendarNetwork` is your SharePoint list, `varBKID` is not part of the list. So you can not add a delegated filter like `varBKID = Blank()` or `IsBlank(varBKID)` to the SharePoint list.

You can try to rewrite your filter like that:

```
ForAll(relatedNetworkIDsFortheCurrentBookingCalendar, 
  Collect(colDelegableresults,
    If(varBKID = Blank(),
      Filter(BookingCalendarNetwork, ActiveStatus.Value = "Active" And 'Network ID' = ThisRecord.ID),
      Filter(BookingCalendarNetwork, ActiveStatus.Value = "Active" And 'Network ID' = ThisRecord.ID And 'Booking Calendar ID' <> varBKID))
      )
);
```